# Change syntax highlighting for filetype

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

Is it possible to change the syntax highlighting language of `.html` files to `.hbs` (handlebars.js plugin) or possibly Blade in PhpStorm, per project?

I am using Underscore.js templates with `{{ .. }}` delimiters, and would like to have syntax highlighting without setting an incorrect file extension.

Comment: Nope. File Type association is an **IDE-wide setting** that affects all projects. The best I can offer is to use double extension (e.g. `*.hbs.html` or any other you may think of) or some unique extension (e.g. `*.hbshtml` -- more inconvenient/impractical).

Comment: If I use a unique extension, how would I go about associating it with another language like .hbs? Thinking .us would be sensible

Comment: Ahh, got it - rename the file to an unused extension, right click and 'Associate with File Type'

Comment: Not really -- this may associate just THAT particular file only (need to verify it actually). The best -- just go to `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types`, find desired file type and add such new pattern there (e.g. `*.us` as per your example). P.S. Double extension in general is better -- you just need to add that pattern to the desired file type (same way as described above). Lets take `*.hbs.html` as an example -- if associated with handlebars plugin/file type, such pattern will have priority over `*.html` as it is more specific (more persistently matching symbols).

Comment: in PHPStorm 2016.2, right-clicking 'Associate with File Type' does remember the filetype association IDE-wide

Comment: I meant different aspect: it might create association with pattern that matches that file ONLY (e.g. `adidas.us` instead of `*.us`). At very least this is behaviour when user creates such association with file names with no extensions (and then wonder: why my all `*.php` files are OK except `index.php` ...)